# decimal value is not printing in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to evaluate the expression and display the output correct to 3  decimal places i tried with below code but it is not working help me how to do that in bash.

```
echo -e "Enter expression to calculate : \c"
read num
let a=num
printf '%f\n' "$a"

Input :  5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7

Output :  17.000000

Desired Output : 17.929
```

Comment: bash can only calculate with integers and the results are only integers.

Comment: @Vijay : Adding to what Cyrus correctly said: Do you have to use bash for your task? If you would use Zsh instead, you would have floats.

Comment: Korn (ksh) shell supports floats as well, I have never understood why bash does not.

Comment: I've never understood why people who need floating-point arithmetic think `bash` et al. are appropriate in the first place. They are designed to facilitate running other programs, not perform computations themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bc`:

```
echo 'scale=3; 5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7' | bc -l
```

Output:

```
17.928
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `let a=num`, you could for example:

```
echo $num | bc 
17.92857142857142857142
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the very rare cases where it's acceptable to let a shell variable expand to become part of the body of an awk script:

```
$ num='5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7'

$ awk 'BEGIN{print '"$num"'}'
17.9286

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%0.3f\n", '"$num"'}'
17.929
```

Comment: Good thinking .